# Azure Table Storage Filter Query

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

I am trying to filter rows against a String Type column. Basically I wanted to filter with part of string. It is very similar to LIKE operation in MySQL.

I have gone through this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/querying-tables-and-entities

However, I couldn't find relevant information for my requirement. Any suggestion more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basically I wanted to filter with part of string. It is very similar
>   to LIKE operation in MySQL.

Azure Tables have limited querying support and unfortunately `LIKE` is unsupported. What you would need to do is fetch all the entities on the client side and then apply the filter there.

Comment: i have millions of rows it is very difficult to handle those at client side. is there any other options?

Comment: If you're looking for strings that starts with certain characters, then there's a way otherwise it's not possible to perform the searches using `LIKE` like functionality.

Comment: it is look like there is support pattern matching in azure table text as of now and accepting

Comment: Can you share more details?

Comment: sorry there was typo in my previous comment. I agreed there is no support for pattern matching. i have accepted your for the same only. thanks

Comment: You got me worried there for a second :). Thanks for clarifying.